# Django auth.models.User query by full name but Chinese name

Tags: sql, django

In Chinese, the name format is `'LastnameFirstname'` (number of characters for both Lastname and Firstname are varied), while in English, it is `'Firstname LastName'`. We can see that in Chinese, the first name last name is swapped (which is not a problem in query here), and the first name last name is NOT separated by whitespace (which caused me this problem).

In SQL, we can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   USER 
WHERE  Concat(last_name, first_name) = 'LastnameFirstName';
```

But how can I do this in Django? Given a FULLNAME string as 'LastnameFirstname', how can I do:

```
User.objects.filter(last_name+firstname=FULLNAME)
```

Another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681708/querying-full-name-in-django) is to create a custom User model and create a new field called "full name", but this solution disables me to use other django built-in functions:

```
class User( models.Model ):
    first_name = models.CharField( max_length=64 )
    last_name = models.CharField( max_length=64 )
    full_name = models.CharField( max_length=128 )
    def save( self, *args, **kw ):
        self.full_name = '{0}{1}'.format( first_name, last_name )
        super( User, self ).save( *args, **kw )
```

I guess there would be a better solution.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either link to the `User` model and create your own class:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    def full_name(self):
        return self.user.last_name + self.user.first_name
    ....
```

or you could subclass the `AbstractUser` model to define your own custom user attributes there:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def full_name(self):
        return self.last_name + self.first_name
```

Then in your settings set the default user model to your new class:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

The `AbstractUser` model only has 3 attributes: `password`,`last_login` and `is_active`. You can define the rest yourself.